# Curious React behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been playing around with React hooks lately and stumbled upon something I couldn't quite figure out.

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState("");

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setFiltered(value);
  }, value);

  return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={filtered}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
  );
```

The code above works fine until I try to **Backspace** or **Delete**. onChange is not triggered. Thoughts?
P.S. The code is not meant for production, just fooling around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code will behave correctly if only you was the second argument to `useLayoutEffect` as an array instead of a string

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState("");

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      setFiltered(value);
    },
    [value]
  );

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={filtered}
      onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
```